# Game Applet not running in 2D game (while loop)

Tags: java, while-loop, compiler-errors, applet

I'm trying to set the dimensions for this game i want to create. The error is at **while(running);** I went over it for an hour but i can't seem to catch the error. I'm using NetbeansIDE also **setPreserredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));** gives me an error, it is asking to Create a method " setPrefferedSize(java.awt.Dimension)"in.com.francesc.game.Game

```
 private void setPreserredSize(Dimension dimension) {
 throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
 }
```

when i run it i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of type
at com.francescstudio.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:67)
at com.francescstudio.game.Start.main(Start.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

heres all the code

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    /**
     *
     * @author francesc
     */

    public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    public static final long SerialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 630;
    public static final Font main = new Font("Bebas Nue Regular", Font.PLAIN, 28);
    private Thread game;
    private boolean running;
    private BufferedImage Image  = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    private long startTime;
    private long elapse;
    private boolean set;

    public Game() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setPreserredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); 
         addKeyListener(this);
    }

    private void update() {
    }

    private void render() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) Image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        // render board 
        g.dispose();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(Image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
    int fps = 0, update = 0;
    long fpsTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double nsPerUpdate = 1000000000.0 / 60;
    // last update time in nano seconds   
    double then = System.nanoTime();
    double unprocessed = 0;

    while (running){

    boolean shouldRender = false;
        double now = System.nanoTime();
        unprocessed += (now - then) / nsPerUpdate;
        then = now;


        // update queque 
        while (unprocessed >= 1) {
            update++;
            update();
            unprocessed--;
            shouldRender = true;
        }

        // render 
        if (shouldRender) {
            fps++;
            render();
            shouldRender = false;
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized start(){ 
        if(running)return; 
        running = true; 
        game = new Thread (this, "game");
        game.start();

    }


     public synchronized stop (){ 
        if(!running) return; 
        running = false; 
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't try to run source code until it compiles cleanly!  BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `while (running) {}` isn't inside of a method, you defined it in the class where it will never get called.

EDIT:
Your code should look something a little more like this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author francesc
 */

public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {
    public static final long SerialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 630;
    public static final Font main = new Font("Bebas Nue Regular", Font.PLAIN, 28);
    private Thread game;
    private boolean running;
    private BufferedImage Image  = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    private long startTime;
    private long elapse;
    private boolean set;

    public Game() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); 
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    private void update() {}
    private void render() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) Image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        // render board 
        g.dispose();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(Image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int fps = 0, update = 0;
        long fpsTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double nsPerUpdate = 1000000000.0 / 60;
        // last update time in nano seconds   
        double then = System.nanoTime();
        double unprocessed = 0;

        while (running) {

            boolean shouldRender = false;
            double now = System.nanoTime();
            unprocessed += (now - then) / nsPerUpdate;
            then = now;

            // update queque 
            while (unprocessed >= 1) {
                update++;
                update();
                unprocessed--;
                shouldRender = true;
            }
            // render 
            if (shouldRender) {
                fps++;
                render();
                shouldRender = false;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized start(){ 
        if(running)return; 
        running = true; 
        game = new Thread (this, "game");
        game.start();

    }
    public synchronized stop (){ 
        if(!running) return; 
        running = false; 
        System.exit(0);
    }
    @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i define it?

Comment: It's actually while (running ) { not semi colon and still getting the error

Comment: I also see that you misspelled `setPreferredSize()` you said `setPreserredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));` where it should be `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));`

Comment: I fixed my code thanks, i just made so spelling errors, thanks!